# JTreeTable selection listener indexes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, jtreetable

I'm using a JTreeTable taken from the java sun example..
I have the following structure:

```
+1
+4
+7
```

which represents the 3 node collapsed..

```
-1
--2
---3
-4
--5
---6
-7
--8
---9
```

And this is the structure expanded. I've added a ListSelectionListener to my ListSelectionModel.

Suppose that I select the node "4" from the collapsed structure.. when I'm into the valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) method,

```
   e.getFirstIndex()  is equal to 1 (because at the index 0 there is the node "1")
```

But it means that the indexes are not absolutely, but related to the state of the structure. In fact if I expand the structure and after I select again the node "4"

```
   e.getFirstIndex() is equal to 3
```

In this way I'm not able to univocally  identify the selected row in my TreeTable.
Do you know how can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need the TreePath to the node, either

```
TreePath path = treeTable.pathForRow(selected);
```

or listen directly the TreeSelectionModel. Not sure if that old treeTable exposes it, though. Better use JXTreeTable from the [SwingX project](http://swingx.java.net), it's gone a big distance since then :-)